# Wordpress - Define Peramlink and call it within URLs within functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to define the WordPress Permalink in functions.php using something like this:

```
<?php $permalink = the_permalink;?>
```

Where "the_permalink" uses the inbuilt WordPress function to get the permalink of the blog, and then use `$permalink` further down in functions.php for example, with an image URL: `<img src="'.$permalink.'/images/image1.png'"/>`

I just need to pull the Peramlink into functions.php for use further down in the file like in the example above.  Either `the_permalink` or `bloginfo('template_directory')` would work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself.  I ended up using the following link structure in my functions.php file

```
<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/map-point-medical.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the ID in your function...such as yourFunction($id) and then use get_permalink($id) in your actual function.

Generally the_permalink is used in situations where you want to display and format a permalink, and get_permalink allows you to pass it to a variable.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink